# ANOVA selects a model with autocorrelated residuals

Tags: time-series, model-selection, likelihood-ratio, generalized-least-squares

I want to know which temperature dataset (Aa1, Bb, Cc, Dd) is/are the best predictor for laying date (medini). First, I used simple linear regression: median`~Aa1+Bb+Cc+Dd`. `VIF` values look good (lower than 2), but there's autocorrelation in the residuals.

I used `gls` regression, and according to the `acf` plot the issue is gone, but model selection with `anova` favours the model without correlation structure, equivalent to simple linear regression with lower AIC. What am I doing wrong? Is there something I should change? Thanks for your help.

Here's my data and code:

```
 structure(list(year = 1991:2015, Aa1 = c(7.37757786087128, 6.19496381436177, 
    8.74930841100149, 6.96713827925121, 5.90561137952305, 6.08383214404014, 
    4.7875869126348, 10.1693591736911, 8.27691928796603, 7.78388000845214, 
    8.39958653143277, 7.2913474992005, 5.7302781132927, 7.92632435581143, 
    7.34873071860154, 8.4242965252079, 6.99040124012018, 9.14322270622033, 
    9.33609829729763, 9.64250656038699, 7.1299713670162, 8.76231211165938, 
    8.54744087799253, 6.74367301003977, 7.7746984649123), Bb = c(-3.18143519666869, 
    -4.39866028668509, 1.78033518645253, -1.09087811744935, 0.781504864298432, 
    -3.35258413204158, -0.147817393686718, 2.20858102713945, 2.78942101113926, 
    0.133688841044735, 7.54352335295978, -3.01163687673316, 4.76122905649298, 
    -0.067047827360323, 6.75503612812823, 4.59545579459801, -3.10992282189532, 
    5.19488285181458, -1.75941821116188, 3.67164104630711, -1.37833278441656, 
    0.889547512007415, -1.47006917494296, 2.96885387269044, -0.599857256084644
    ), Cc = c(-3.14888958162661, -5.09421300863669, 0.859087760125301, 
    -3.77697950592429, -2.35219581389364, -3.95249382467829, -3.33432632797512, 
    -1.20699309912482, -2.85922008621721, -3.713746771849, -1.33312677641961, 
    -2.46973133916438, -1.72655447645258, -3.11445919729557, -1.25910057594707, 
    -1.57561781314935, -4.75200348290639, 0.160156234390008, -0.626073828499617, 
    -1.68243433179146, -3.08619266129513, -2.68649754048611, -4.31190628871281, 
    -1.472913440597, -3.08940582665639), Dd = c(-1.37625014361211, 
    -5.05573658662682, -1.18101124482994, -2.52954173368564, -0.261439424402551, 
    -3.97714305204502, -1.98631268669575, 1.59101167566638, -3.05814029469207, 
    -5.33150060317094, -2.69995009478398, -2.56073069852939, -1.92038394703582, 
    -2.70067713120402, -0.0833998736213011, -3.31705501780788, -3.06175213982075, 
    -1.19264921300549, -2.02601964613968, -2.31430484547332, -1.1192687988281, 
    -1.61056051815255, -1.08186142865347, -2.30663057215071, -2.99631168141082
    ), medini = c(162L, 172L, 157L, 161L, 161L, 166L, 161L, 158L, 
    168L, 168L, 164L, 167L, 160L, 163L, 163L, 165L, 167L, 162L, 164L, 
    164L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 162L, 163L)), .Names = c("year", "Aa1", 
    "Bb", "Cc", "Dd", "medini"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -25L))


require(nlme)
m15 = gls(medini~Aa1+Bb+Cc+Dd ,data=LDT)
plot(ACF(m15,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

m15.1 <- update(m15, correlation=corARMA(form = ~ 1,p=1))
plot(ACF(m15.1,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

m15.1.1 <- update(m15, correlation=corARMA(form = ~ 1,p=1,q=1))
plot(ACF(m15.1.1,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

m15.2 <- update(m15, correlation=corARMA(form = ~ 1,p=2))
plot(ACF(m15.2,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

anova(m15.2,m15)
anova(m15.2,m15.1)
anova(m15.2,m15.1.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the correlation stricture with degrees 1 is not sufficient to detect a change, even though the ACF plot is definitely better looking. If you try a correlation structure with degree 2 and do not omit the q term it detects a change

```
m15 = gls(medini~Aa1+Bb+Cc+Dd ,data=LDT)
plot(ACF(m15,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

m15.1 <- update(m15, correlation=corARMA(form = ~ 1,p=1))
plot(ACF(m15.1,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

m15.1.1 <- update(m15, correlation=corARMA(form = ~ 1,p=1,q=1))
plot(ACF(m15.1.1,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

m15.2 <- update(m15, correlation=corARMA(form = ~ 1,p=2,q=1))
plot(ACF(m15.2,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

m15.2.2 <- update(m15, correlation=corARMA(form = ~ 1,p=2,q=2))
plot(ACF(m15.2.2,resType="normalized"),alpha=0.05)

anova(m15,m15.1,m15.1.1,m15.2,m15.2.2)

        Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
m15         1  6 116.2450 122.2194 -52.12248                        
m15.1       2  7 117.5666 124.5368 -51.78332 1 vs 2 0.678327  0.4102
m15.1.1     3  8 118.3427 126.3085 -51.17133 2 vs 3 1.223983  0.2686
m15.2       4  9 116.4852 125.4468 -49.24260 3 vs 4 3.857445  0.0495
m15.2.2     5 10 114.0713 124.0287 -47.03567 4 vs 5 4.413861  0.0356
```